# Elasticsearch River - java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to create a Elastic search river for my MongoDB. I am using `elasticsearch-mapper-attachments` and `elasticsearch-river-mongodb` plug-ins. The issue I have is I get a complaint about `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map`

Here is the index that I create:

```
{
    "type": "mongodb",
    "mongodb": {
        "collection": "config_files", 
        "db": "tore_dev"
    },
    "index": "config_files" 
}
```

---

Here is the command:

```
one@old-dash ~/river $ curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_river/config_files/_meta" -d @create.json |  python -m json.tool
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   220  100    84  100   136   3032   4909 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5230
{
    "_id": "_meta", 
    "_index": "_river", 
    "_type": "config_files", 
    "_version": 1, 
    "created": true
}
one@old-dash ~/river $
```

---

Here is the status of it:

```
one@old-dash ~/river $ curl localhost:9200/_river/config_files/_status |  python -m json.tool
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   640  100   640    0     0  30247      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 33684
{
    "_id": "_status", 
    "_index": "_river", 
    "_source": {
        "error": "CreationException[Guice creation errors:\n\n1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map\n  at org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver.<init>(Unknown Source)\n  while locating org.elasticsearch.river.mongodb.MongoDBRiver\n  while locating org.elasticsearch.river.River\n\n1 error]; nested: ClassCastException[java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map]; ", 
        "node": {
            "id": "57f4LnVMSn2xDlo1Es0meQ", 
            "name": "Wicked", 
            "transport_address": "inet[/10.1.23.69:9300]"
        }
    }, 
    "_type": "config_files", 
    "_version": 1, 
    "found": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. I was passing a `string` into the `index` field:

```
    ...
    "index": "config_files" 
    ....
```

Instead I needed to [pass an `object`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html#inner-objects)  into the index field:

```
{
    "type": "mongodb",
    "mongodb": {
        "collection": "config_files", 
        "db": "tore_dev"
    },
    "index": {
        "name": "mongo_index",
        "type": "config_files"
    }
}
```

The object is probably expressed in Elasticsearch internals as the `java.util.Map`, as they describe the `objects`:

> known in other languages as a hash, hashmap, dictionary or associative array.

So this explains the error message,  `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map`